# Stripe get card details using by retrieving the customer

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to get the customers card details with stripe I only have the customer id and the payment_method id how can I use this ids to retrieve the card details. Primarily the last four digits of the card

I already tried buy retrieving the customer object but it does not have the last 4 digits of the card. does anyone know how to retrieve it using customer id or payment method id

```
stripe.customers.retrieve(
    req.body.customerId,
    function(err, customer) {
      // asynchronously called
      res.send(customer)
    }
);
```

Comment: If you don't have the card id, you can list all of the cards using the customer id (and then retrieve the `last4` property): https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/list

Comment: @devlincarnate hey I don't have any cards on the list cause i created a customer that i can charge every month, I didnt create card. I use the customer id to charge the customer. so listing the cards wont help me cause their are no card on the list

Comment: If you don't have any cards saved for the customer, then you can't retrieve what isn't there.  Perhaps you need to clarify your question?

Comment: There's also `last4` saved on the payment method details:  https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/retrieve

Comment: yes thanks i got it

Answer (score 0):

Check `sources` on the `Customer` object. E.g.

```
stripe.customers.retrieve(
    req.body.customerId,
    function(err, customer) {
        // asynchronously called
        res.send(customer.sources.data[0].last4)
    }
);
```

Reference: https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object

Comment: my customer.sources.data[0] is empty i don't have any sources on the object

Comment: @Max but you have the `payment_method` ID? Check the `PaymentMethod` object, e.g. paymentMethod.card.last4. See: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object

Answer (score 0):

```
 stripe.paymentMethods.retrieve(
     req.body.paymentId,
    function(err, paymentMethod) {
      // asynchronously called
      res.send(paymentMethod.card.last4)
    }
  );
```